# Debug cordova app on xcode. Error

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap

How to fix this error

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVLogger in:
>       /Users/nazarkalituk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPP-emnjcrdbcjgsjvblqcxjuovvzffs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MYAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYAPP.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVLogger.o
>       /Users/nazarkalituk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPP-emnjcrdbcjgsjvblqcxjuovvzffs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a(CDVLogger.o)
>   ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error implies you have two copies of `CDVLogger` in your project.

This likely because you have [cordova-plugin-console](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console) installed which [contains these files](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console/tree/master/src/ios) - you can check with `cordova plugin ls` - and you also have `cordova-ios@4.5.0` (or greater) in your project, which now [contains these files also](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/tree/master/CordovaLib/Classes/Private/Plugins/CDVLogger) - check your platform version with `cordova platform ls`.

To remedy the problem, remove `cordova-plugin-console` from your project:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-console
```

You may also need to remove/re-add the iOS platform to rebuild the project:

```
cordova platform rm ios --nosave && cordova platform add ios --nosave
```